# Get distance of element from top of the window which changes when user scrolls

Tags: javascript, html, distance

I need to find distance between top of the window to the element. I can calculate that distance using `offsetTop`, But in `offsetTop` it only gives element's distance from top of the window, What I want is to decrease the distance when user scrolls up. And increase the distance when user scrolls down. So how to achieve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `.getBoundingClientRect()`.

See more info here: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect